# How to test for raised exception in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, exception

I've got a Django project in which I have a function which I want to test. Simplified, the function looks like this:

```
class InvalidUrlError(Exception):
    pass

def get_info_from_url(url):
    try:
        return url.split(':')[1].split('/')[0]
    except Exception:
        raise InvalidUrlError(f"Invalid url: {url}")
```

And my test looks like this:

```
class ToolsTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_get_info_from_url_wrong_formatted_url(self):
        self.assertRaises(InvalidUrlError, get_info_from_url("https://acc.images.data.ourcompany.com/"))
```

When I run it though, I get the following output:

```
$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
....E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_info_from_url_wrong_formatted_url (checker.tests.ToolsTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kramer65/repos/auth-proxy/app/checker/tools.py", line 10, in get_info_from_url
    return url.split(':')[1].split('/')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kramer65/repos/auth-proxy/app/checker/tests.py", line 57, in test_get_info_from_url_wrong_formatted_url
    self.assertRaises(InvalidUrlError, get_info_from_url("https://acc.images.data.ourcompany.com/"))
  File "/home/kramer65/repos/auth-proxy/app/checker/tools.py", line 15, in get_info_from_url
    raise InvalidUrlError(f"Invalid url: {url}")
checker.tools.InvalidUrlError: Invalid url: https://acc.images.data.ourcompany.com/

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.037s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Why does it raise the exceptions, instead of passing the tests? I think I do a comparable thing in another test, which works great.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You need to pass a callable** instead of calling the function itself. [Unittest docs for assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)

So change it to:

```py
class ToolsTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_get_info_from_url_wrong_formatted_url(self):
        self.assertRaises(InvalidUrlError, get_info_from_url, "https://acc.images.data.ourcompany.com/")
```

Other option is to use `assertRaises` as context manager like this:

```py
class ToolsTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_get_info_from_url_wrong_formatted_url(self):
        with self.assertRaises(InvalidUrlError):
            get_info_from_url("https://acc.images.data.ourcompany.com/")
```